# How use custom analog clock face in Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android

I've modified a sample Analog Clock program so it is just the hands. I want to use my own images of clock faces behind the hands. But I can't find a way that doesn't cover up the hands. The clock size doesn't change (always full screen). I'm using canvas draw commands to make the hands. Is there a common method to do this?

Comment: Please show the core of your code, welcome to StackOverflo, we'll help you if you help us

Comment: This is the example i am attempting to modify... https://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-to-draw-an-analog-clock-on-android-with-the-canvas-2d-api/

Comment: NM - it was  simple android:background="@drawable.myfile"